# HTML5 iOS get image but force camera use

Tags: ios, html, camera

I know its very possible to get a photo from the native camera or file system in iOS using the following code:

```
<input type="file" capture="camera" accept="image/*">
```

This allows me to choose from the camera or the filesystem. I want to force the user to open the camera, only giving them the option to use the camera to input an image.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm guessing this won't ever become a feature as `getUserMedia` will supersede it.